# Как осуществить проверку почищенных кук (cookie)?

Tags: javascript, cookie, php

Я делаю скрипт задания для почтовика и первым из условий - почистите куки (cookie), - встал вопрос, а как проверить, что в браузере удалена вся история и почищены куки посещенных страниц?

Скрипт желательно на Jscript, но на худой конец можно и PHP. Вопрос в следующем: в каком направлении я должен двигаться? Хотелось бы своим умом дойти до решения, но и от готовой инструкции не откажусь.

с уважением Le Grol.

Comment: а можно проверить отсутствие записей в истории?

Comment: мне важно проверить отсутсвие кук основных поисковиков (что бы пользователь их почистил)

Comment: просто я видел скрипт  такой своми глазами но автор не продает тайну проверки почищены куки.

Comment: вот видео http://youtu.be/R98BRtgDkkQ здесь наглядно показано то что я хочу,но не могу сообразить как осуществлен данный режим проверки, что история и куки удалены.

Answer (score 1):

Браузер дает доступ только к кукам того же сайта с которого был сделан запрос. Соотвественно можно очистить только свои куки.
На счет истории - сомневаюсь что с ней можно производить подобные манипуляции на уровне скрипта. История - это фича конкретного браузера, по идее ее может не быть в принципе.

Answer (score 1):

Вам всё верно написал [[@nMike](/users/2650/nmike)](/users/2650/nmike). Та страница может только проверить куки конкретно на своём домене, а не в браузере в целом, так как такое действие запрещено политикой безопасности всех браузеров. И явно понятно, что скрипт при первом заходе вешает какие-то куки к своему домену, и проверяет их отсутствие. На javascript самый короткий способ почистить куки - document.cookie = ""

Comment: спасибо что прояснили ситуацию, буду работать в этом направлении.

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятна постановка вопроса. Для своего домена это сделать легко.

```
// сброс cookie установленную для всего наддомена для корневой директории

PHP: if ( isset($_COOKIE['name']) ) setcookie('name', '', time()-3600, '/', '.domain.com');

JS: var expires = new Date(new Date().getTime() - 3600000).toGMTString(); 
document.cookie = name + "=" + "; expires=" + expires + "; path=/; domain=domain.com";

jQuery: $.cookie('name', '', {path: '/', expires: }); // плагин jQuery.cookies
```

Comment: вот видео http://youtu.be/R98BRtgDkkQ  здесь наглядно показано то что я хочу,но не могу сообразить как осуществлен данный режим проверки, что история и куки удалены.